# Sort Array of Dictionary of Dictionary key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

How can i sort array using **Firt_name** Key.

I used this Code but its not helpful.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"user.first_name"ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

{
                "created_at" = "";
                "updated_at" = "";
                user =             {
                    "first_name" = Gary;
                    "full_contact" = "null 5555555555";
                    "full_name" = "Gary123";
                };
     },
```

Comment: NSArray *sortedArray = [[array valueforkey=@"user"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@first_name"ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

Comment: Thanks for the reply nut i tried @"first_name" also  @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: before sorting print your array thats [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

Answer (score 1):

by using  NSSortDescriptor you can do that.

> An NSSortDescriptor object describes a basis for ordering objects by
>   specifying the property to use to compare the objects, the method to
>   use to compare the properties, and whether the comparison should be
>   ascending or descending. Instances of NSSortDescriptor are immutable.

```
 +(NSMutableArray *)SortArray : (NSMutableArray *)arrOriginal{
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
        sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Firt_name" ascending:YES
            comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
            return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
            }];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        NSArray *sortedArray;
        sortedArray = [arrOriginal
                       sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [arrOriginal removeAllObjects];
        [arrOriginal addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
        return arrOriginal;
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Narendra Pandey. It works. But by using  **@"user.First_name"**.

{
                "created_at" = "";
                "updated_at" = "";
                user =             {
                    "first_name" = Gary;
                    "full_contact" = "null 5555555555";
                    "full_name" = "Gary123";
                };
     },

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below lines of code and check:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"user.first_name" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

NSArray *sortedArray=[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors,nil]];
```

You can read more about `NSSortDescriptor` at below link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE